# Recursão - Desejo contar quantas vezes os algarismos 3 e 4 aparecem

Tags: python-3.x

Desejo contar quantas vezes os algarismos 3 e 4 aparecem. O quê está dando errado?

```
def count(x):
  y=0
  if x[0]=='':
    print(y)
    return
  if x[0]=='3':
    y=y+1
  return count(x[1:])

count('23334')
```

Comment: Dúvida: A solução deve, obrigatoriamente, utilizar recursão ou você utilizou achando que seria a melhor forma?

Comment: É um exercício que deve usar, obrigatoriamente, a recursão

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problema

Seu código tem alguns problemas de lógica. Segue o teste de mesa para a entrada `23334`:

1. A função `count` é chamada com `x = '23334'`;
2. O valor de `y` é definido como 0;
3. Verifica a posição 0 de `x`. Falso, segue em frente;
4. Verifica se na posição 0 há um 3. Falso, segue em frente;
5. Retorna o valor de `count('3334')`;
6. A função `count` é chamada com `x = '3334'`;
7. O valor de `y` é definido como 0;
8. Verifica a posição 0 de `x`. Falso, segue em frente;
9. Verifica se na posição 0 há um 3. Verdadeiro, incrementa `y` (`y = 1`);
10. Retorna o valor de `count('334')`;
11. A função `count` é chamada com `x = '334'`;
12. O valor de `y` é definido como 0;
13. Verifica a posição 0 de `x`. Falso, segue em frente;
14. Verifica se na posição 0 há um 3. Verdadeiro, incrementa `y` (`y = 1`);
15. Retorna o valor de `count('34')`;
16. A função `count` é chamada com `x = '34'`;
17. O valor de `y` é definido como 0;
18. Verifica a posição 0 de `x`. Falso, segue em frente;
19. Verifica se na posição 0 há um 3. Verdadeiro, incrementa `y` (`y = 1`);
20. Retorna o valor de `count('4')`;
21. A função `count` é chamada com `x = '4'`;
22. O valor de `y` é definido como 0;
23. Verifica a posição 0 de `x`. Falso, segue em frente;
24. Verifica se na posição 0 há um 3. Falso, segue em frente;
25. Retorna o valor de `count('')`;
26. A função `count` é chamada com `x = ''`;
27. O valor de `y` é definido como 0;
28. Verifica a posição 0 de `x`. **Erro! Não existe posição 0 em `x`**;
29. Desconsiderando o erro: Imprime `y` (`y = 0`);
30. Retorna um valor nulo para o item 25;
31. Do item 25 é retornado nulo para o item 20;
32. Do item 20 é retornado nulo para o item 15;
33. Do item 15 é retornado nulo para o item 10;
34. Do item 10 é retornado nulo para o item 5;
35. Do item 5 é retornado nulo para o item 1;

Resumindo: seu código dá erro e você omitiu esta informação na pergunta.

> IndexError: string index out of range

O mesmo é explicado no item 28 do teste de mesa.

E mesmo que sendo desconsiderado o erro, sua função iria imprimir na tela o valor 9, retornando um valor nulo.

## Solução

Primeiro, vamos evitar que o erro aconteça. Para verificar se o valor de `x` não é nulo, basta fazer `if x: ...`. Desta forma, nossa função ficará:

```
def count(x):
    y = 0

    if x:
        ... # Implementado posteriormente

    return y
```

Pois se `x` for nulo, retorna o valor de `y`, que será 0. Agora, dentro do `if`, garantimos que `x` não é nulo e que existe a posição 0. Podemos verificar se o mesmo possui o algarismo 3:

```
def count(x):
    y = 0

    if x:
        if x[0] == '3':
            y += 1

        ... # Implementado posteriormente

    return y
```

Se o algarismo for 3, incrementamos o valor de `y` em 1, mas independente se é ou não o algarismo 3, o valor de `y` deverá ser incrementado conforme a quantia de algarismos 3 no restante da string. Este foi o outro erro seu: você não acumulou o valor atual de `y` com o valor que é retornado das próximas chamadas da função. Para isso fazemos:

```
def count(x):
    y = 0

    if x:
        if x[0] == '3':
            y += 1

        y += count(x[1:])

    return y
```

E desta forma nossa função já está completa e funcional. Se chamarmos ela passando como parâmetro o valor `'23334'`, a resposta será 3.

> Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Hz7e/0).

Se você deseja contar tanto os algarismos 3 quanto os algarismos 4, pode fazer:

```
def count(x):
    y = 0

    if x:
        if x[0] in ('3', '4'):
            y += 1

        y += count(x[1:])

    return y


print(count("23334"))
```

> Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Hz7e/1).

O teste de mesa desta minha solução eu deixo como atividade para você fazer.

---

#### Solução sem utilizar recursividade

Para uma solução sem utilizar recursividade, bastaria utilizar o método [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) do objeto *string*:

```
>>> print("23334".count("3"))
3

>>> print("23334".count("4"))
1
```